# How to change route in class in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, controller, routes

I defined the default_controller as "Home" in *routes.php*. When example.com is written as url, the page works. It also works when example.com/home is written as url. Could I show 404 error page when example.com/home is entered as url?

The other question is I have two functions in Home.php in controller folder. When I call a function such as contact, the url is seen like example.com/home/contact. Could I show the url such as example.com/contact instead of .com/home/contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done, with Routes.

Your first question;

"Could I show 404 error page when example.com/home is entered as url?"

```
$route['home'] = '404';
```

This would show a 404 page whenever someone tries to visit /home. If you visit / it would show the default controller.

The second question:

"Could I show the url such as example.com/contact instead of .com/home/contact?"

Again, this is pretty easy with Routes.

```
$route['contact'] = 'home/contact';
```

Anyone who visits /contact would see the home/contact method.

Hope this helps.